# Make openam/opensso return role name instead of role universal id

Tags: authentication, openam, role, opensso

I'm using OpenAM 9.5.2 for authenticating users on an application. The authentication works well but I'm having issues to get user memberships from final application.

I've defined the group "somegroup" in openam and added my user to this group. Now in my application, I want to test if authenticated users is member of this group. If I'm testing it with:

```
request.isUserInRole("somegroup");
```

I get `false` result. Actually, I have to test

```
request.isUserInRole("id=somegroup,ou=group,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net");
```

in order to get a `true` response.

I know that it's possible to define a privileged attribute mapping list in the sso agent configuration to map `id=somegroup,ou=group,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net` on `somegroup`, but it's not suitable in my situation since roles and groups are stored in an external database. It's not convenient to define role in database and mapping in sso agent conf.

So my question : is there a way to make openam use the "short" (i.e. `somegroup`) group name instead of its long universal id ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just one remark.

I've performed some researches in openam sources and it seems to confirm that the role name stored in repository is replaced by universalId when openam build the request. This is performed in `com.sun.identity.idm.server.IdRepoJAXRPCObjectImpl.java` class:

```
public Set getMemberships_idrepo(String token, String type, String name,
                                 String membershipType, String amOrgName,
                                 String amsdkDN
) throws RemoteException, IdRepoException, SSOException {
  SSOToken ssoToken = getSSOToken(token);
  Set results = new HashSet();
  IdType idtype = IdUtils.getType(type);
  IdType mtype = IdUtils.getType(membershipType);
  Set idSet = idServices.getMemberships(ssoToken, idtype, name, mtype, amOrgName, amsdkDN);
  if (idSet != null) {
    Iterator it = idSet.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      AMIdentity id = (AMIdentity) it.next();
      results.add(IdUtils.getUniversalId(id));
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: I think this is only done to get over some data to the client, on the client side, it will probably reconstruct a dummy AMIdentity object, so any code could call methods on it like getAttributes. (So I wouldn't consider this as the main reason)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible currently with out of box code. In case you have limited amount of groups, then privileged attribute mapping could be a way to go, but if not, then the issue gets more complicated.

You could try to change the AmRealm implementation (authenticateInternal method) to match your requirements and hook the new class into the container-specific ServiceResolver class (like http://sources.forgerock.org/browse/openam/trunk/opensso/products/j2eeagents/tomcat/v6/source/com/sun/identity/agents/tomcat/v6/AmTomcatAgentServiceResolver.java?r=700&r=700&r=700 )

You can also create a JIRA issue about providing a config property to put membership information into roles in non-UUID format.

Comment: I've tried to modify openam agent (AmJBossLoginModule because I'm using jboss) in order to convert roles name when they're asked by app server. For my test I've added a tricky bit of code in `validatePassword()` method, which removes unwanted part of the role name (i.e. the prefix `id=` and the suffix `,ou=group,dc=opensso,dc=java,dc=net`). Then I've re-compiled the `agent.jar` lib with my modified class and it seems to be working now: I get "short" version of my role name. Now I have to find a better class for applying this modification since I don't want to be jboss dependant.